# jetty 8 multipart/form-data requests

Tags: java, jetty, embed, multipartform-data, jetty-8

I'm using Jetty 8 as embedded server in a project. Everything works as expected, except multipart/form-data requests.

My servlet which has to process the multipart/form-data requests works fine, - I've tested it with the RunJettyRun plugin of eclipse. That's why the embedded server code must be the guilty part.

My code follows the jetty examples like [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty). I've searching the internet since 2 days, but didn't find out how to config jetty.

Every hint is welcome,
kind regards,
Sea

Comment: Not enough information in that question to know what you are doing?

Answer (score 1):

Things can be so simple.
You just have to set the MultipartConfig to your ServletHolder. For example:

```
ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(YourServlet.class);
sh.getRegistration().setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement("yourTempLocation", 1048576, 1048576, 262144));
```

Just annotate *YourServlet* with @MultipartConfig and you have full access to the multipart/form-data.

Answer (score 0):

You can either set multipart support through by adding the required class to the server directly,

```
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList classlist = org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault(server);
    classlist.addAfter("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration");
    classlist.addBefore("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");
```

or adding the required configurations to your web app context, as in:

```
WebAppContext myWebAppContext= new WebAppContext();     
myWebAppContext.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] { new AnnotationConfiguration(), new WebInfConfiguration(),
            new WebXmlConfiguration(), new FragmentConfiguration(), new EnvConfiguration(), new PlusConfiguration(),
            new JettyWebXmlConfiguration() });
```